# Именованный цикл?

Tags: javascript, java, любой-язык, терминология

Встретил на YouTube видео (точнее, шорт), который начинается так:

> Этот вопрос ставит в тупик даже опытного разработчика: как создать именованный цикл? Каждый из нас пользуется циклами, но далеко не каждый знает, что циклу можно дать имя.

И речь там идёт, конечно же, о метке перед циклом типа такого:

```
OUTER: for (int x : a) {
 for (int y : b) {
  if (x + y == z) {
   break OUTER;
  }
 }
}
```

Многие комментаторы написали, что это же просто метка. Да и у меня сначала была такая мысль. Но потом я стал обдумывать ситуацию, и чем больше я думал, тем  больше вариант автора с "именованным циклом" казался мне более подходящим.

Во многих языках к меткам обычно прилагается возможность перейти на них (`goto`) и метка по сути олицетворяет некую позицию в коде. Для метки неважно, что перед ней и что после неё, она - лишь позиция в коде - как курсор в тексе.

В джаве же, как и в большинстве других языков, где метка ставится перед циклами и блоками, к ней не прилагается `goto` - вместо него даются команды управления циклом/блоком `break` и `continue` с меткой. Тут уже важно, перед чем стоит метка. Она олицетворяет не позицию, а весь statement, перед которым стоит, и является инструментом воздействия на этот участок. Кажется, что для такого вполне подходит понятие "имя", а цикл или блок кода можно назвать именованным.

Гугл выдаёт крайне мало результатов по сочетанию "именованный цикл", так что я так понимаю, что это название (почти) никто не использует. Почему так? Просто никто не задумывался над таким вариантом имени и такой интерпретацией метки, или же я чего-то не замечаю и это название на самом деле не подходит?

Comment: Какая разница как вы называете редко используемый механизм, который уточняет работу `break` и `continue`? Он настолько мало влияет, что едва ли заслуживает рассуждений о его имени.

Comment: *"я так понимаю, что это название (почти) никто не использует"* --- скорее просто автор видео сделал кликбейт, не более того...

Comment: чисто технически цикл с меткой называется `labeled loop` - что в принципе можно перевести и как именованный и как цикл с меткой - ни видно особой разницы

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, заголовок там действительно кликбейтный, но этого сочетания слов в нём нет. В коде вопроса в комментарии есть ссылка на видео, если интересно.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, т. е. если что-то редко используется, то название ему не нужно? Как-то не могу согласиться...

Comment: @Grundy, да, по "labeled loop" полно результатов. А на mdn есть страница "labeled statement", которая в русском варианте озаглавлена просто "метка".

Comment: Редко используется - название не важно. Важен механизм: вы можете приписать циклу метку и использовать эту метку в `break` и `continue`. Даже "метка" - это слишком роскошный термин. Но "метка" пришла из C, где это имя куда важнее. Не тратим время, идём дальше, к вещам более важным и интересным.

Comment: @Qwertiy не, мне не интересно. Чтобы пользоваться своими пальцами, мне не нужно знать какие процессы внутри моего организма происходят и как они специфически называются. Лучше двигать пальцами от этого я не стану.... тут точно так же...

Comment: Если какому-то блоку кода понадобилось имя (или комментарий), то его выносят в метод с именем. Поэтому вместо термина "именованный цикл" все используют термины "метод/функция/процедура". Я так думаю.

Comment: кмк потому что явовская реализация единственный хоть чего то стоящий вариант(из тех которые могу представить), метки ведь крайней опасны риском заблудиться в них, создав не контролируемый бесконечный цикл. в подавляющем большинстве `CASE's` которые на ум приходят, циклом можно обернуть тот же СВИЧ, или вереницу `if{}elseif{}else{}`, для более местного применения можно обойтись тернарником / дерганьем данных из массива по индексу. все они по безопаснее меток будут. `Лучше двигать пальцами от знания названий требухи я не стану` это до первого столкновения с болячкой лично - без врача

Answer (score -1):

> Почему так? Просто никто не задумывался над таким вариантом имени и такой интерпретацией метки, или же я чего-то не замечаю и это название на самом деле не подходит?

Потому, что такого названия не существует. Вы можете как угодно называть цикл, но в Java все укладывается в спецификацию, где четко определено, что такое цикл и какое у него название. Придумывать из головы какое-нибудь название *ещё* бессмысленно и бесполезно.

В примере метка поставлена на утверждение цикла `for`. Два утверждения - следовательно два цикла. Может быть кто-то скажет, что метка -`break label` тоже является циклом, и тогда будет уже не два цикла а три. Но это на самом деле не так, а вот если действительно создать третий цикл, то нужно избавиться от  метки `break label`. Но это к сожалению не всегда возможно, поэтому утверждения `break label` и `continue label` до сих пор существуют в языке.

Comment: Для начала, в джаве нет goto.

Comment: @Qwertiy В твоей джаве может быть и нет (наверно я давно уже не пользовался им), хотя `break label`  - это то же самое, что я и имел ввиду. По поводу goto читай [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4547764/573032).

Comment: [The Java™ Tutorials: Java Language Keywords](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html): _The keywords `const` and `goto` are reserved, even though they are not currently used_

Comment: Перевод `statement` как "утверждение" немного режет глаз, вроде бы принято использовать термин "инструкция", [статья на Хабре: "Русскоязычная спецификация языка Java"](https://habr.com/ru/articles/330624/)

Comment: @NowhereMan 1. `goto` - ключевое слово языка Java. Его до сих пор не убрали из языка, несмотря на время и количество версий. См. линк из предыдущего комментария. 2. Инструкция - это совсем другое понятие из других языков, и переводится как directive.

Comment: @Qwertiy Если этот ответ помог решить проблему, то его надо помечать галочкой и по возможности голосовать за. Так вы поможете и себе и другим, кто нуждается в решении подобной проблемы.